# Maven: Don't use version installed on application server

Tags: java, spring, websphere

I have a war and want to deploy it on a websphere application server.

The application server has `slf4j`, version **1.4.2** installed.
However, my application requires at least version **1.6.1**.

Here's the dependency defined in my POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I can build the application successfully, but everytime I try to launch it on the websphere server, I get the following error:

```
DispatcherSer E org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/timer-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: org.slf4j.Logger
```

What do I have to do so that my application uses version 1.6.1, and ignores the already installed version on the server?

Related Question: [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395314/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-getsingletonlor)

Comment: Check if you class loading strategy is configured PARENT_LAST. Apart from that this has nothing to do with Maven ONLY Websphere.

Comment: @khmarbaise Is it possible to change this setting inside the application when I generate `war` files?

Comment: No. Cause it would be a kind of a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: Which jars end up in the war's WEB-INF/lib I wonder? Is the slf4j API jar also in there, or is only the log4j12 implementation jar present?

Comment: @Gimby Yes, it's also in there.